# Unexpected behavior of binary conversions (COALESCE vs. ISNULL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you comment on what approach shown below is preferable? I hope the question will not be blocked as "opinionated". I would like to believe there is an explanation that makes that clear.

**Context:** I have a code for mirroring 3rd party table contents to my own table (optimization). It worked some time flawlessly until the size/modification of the database reached some threshold.

The optimization is based on *row version* values of more tables, and remembering the maximum of the values from the source tables. This way I am able to update my local table incrementally, much faster than rebuilding it from time to time from scratch.

The problem started to appear when the row-version value exceeded the 4byte value. After some effort, I have spotted that the upper 4 bytes of the `binary(8)` value were set to 0. Later, the suspect was found to have a form `COALESCE(MAX(row_version), 1)`.

The COALESCE was used to cover the case when the local table is fresh, containing now data -- for comparing the `MAX(row_version)` of source tables with something meaningful.

**The examples to show the bug:** To simulate the last mentioned situation, I want to convert the NULL value of the `binary(8)` column to 1. I am adding also the `ISNULL` usage that was added later. The original code contained the COALESCE only.

```
DECLARE @bin8null binary(8) = NULL

SELECT 'bin NULL' AS the_variable, @bin8null AS value
SELECT 'coalesce 1' AS op, COALESCE(@bin8null, 1) AS good_value
SELECT 'coalesce 1 + convert' AS op, CONVERT(binary(8), COALESCE(@bin8null, 1)) AS good_value
SELECT 'isnull 1' AS op, ISNULL(@bin8null, 1) AS good_value
SELECT 'isnull 0x1' AS op, ISNULL(@bin8null, 0x1) AS bad_value
```

(There is a bug in the image `coalesce 0x1 + convert` fixed later in the code to `coalesce 1 + convert`, but not fixed in the image.)

The application bug appeared when the binary value was bigger than the part that could be stored in 4 bytes. Here the `0xAAAAAAAA` was used. (Actually, the `0x00000001` was the case, and it was difficult to spot that the single 1 was changed to 0.)

```
DECLARE @bin8 binary(8) = 0xAAAAAAAA01BB3A35

SELECT 'bin' AS the_variable, @bin8 AS value
SELECT 'coalesce 1' AS op, COALESCE(@bin8, 1) AS bad_value
SELECT 'coalesce 1 + convert' AS op, CONVERT(binary(8), COALESCE(@bin8, 1)) AS bad_value
SELECT 'coalesce 0x1 + convert ' AS op, CONVERT(binary(8), COALESCE(@bin8, 0x1)) AS good_value
SELECT 'isnull 1' AS op, ISNULL(@bin8, 1) AS good_value
SELECT 'isnull 0x1' AS op, ISNULL(@bin8, 0x1) AS good_value
```

When executed in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio on MS-SQL Server 2014, the result looks like this:
[image: The results]

**Description -- my understanding:** The `COALESCE()` seems to derive the type of the result from the type of the last processed argument. This way, the non-NULL `binary(8)` was converted to `int`, and that lead to the loss of upper 4 bytes. (See the 2nd and 3rd red `bad_value` on the picture. The difference between the two cases is only in decimal/hexadecimal form of display.)

On the other hand, the `ISNULL()` seems to preserve the type of the first argument, and converts the second value to that type. One should be careful to understand that `binary(8)` is more like a series of bytes. The interpretation as one large integer is only the interpretation. Hence, the `0x1` as the default value does not expand as 8bytes integer and produces bad value.

**My solution:** So, I have fixed the bug using `ISNULL(MAX(row_version), 1)`. Is that correct?

Comment: [Is null](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-types) Returns the same type as check_expression. If a literal NULL is provided as check_expression, returns the datatype of the replacement_value. 

[coalesce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-types) Returns the data type of expression with the highest data type precedence. Since int is way higher than binary/varbinary, coalesce will return int in `coalesce(@varbinary, 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug. They're documented to handle [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) differently. `COALESCE` determines the data type of the output based on examining *all* of the arguments, while ISNULL has a more simplistic approach of inspecting only the first argument. (Both still need to contain values which are all compatible, meaning they are all *possible* to convert to the determined output type.)

From the [`COALESCE` topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql):

> Returns the data type of *expression* with the highest data type precedence.

The [`ISNULL` topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql) does not make this distinction in the same way, but implicitly states that the first expression determines the type:

> *replacement_value* must be of a type that is implicitly convertible to the type of *check_expression*.

I have a similar example (and describe several other differences between `COALESCE` and `ISNULL`) [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand). Basically:

```
DECLARE @int int, @datetime datetime;
SELECT COALESCE(@int, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

> -- works because datetime has a higher precedence than the ***chosen*** output type, int
>
>   `2020-08-20 09:39:41.763`

```
GO
DECLARE @int int, @datetime datetime;
SELECT ISNULL(@int, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

> -- fails because int, the ***first (and chosen)*** output type, has a lower precedence than datetime
> `Msg 257, Level 16, State 3`
> `Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.`

Answer (score 3):

Let me start of by saying:

#### This is ***not*** a "bug".

`ISNULL` and `COALESCE` are *not* the same function, and operate quite differently.

`ISNULL` takes 2 parameters, and returns the second parameter if the first has a value `NULL`. If the 2 parameters are different datatypes, then the dataype of the **first** datatype is returned (implicitly casting the second value).

`COALESCE` takes 2+ parameters, and returns the first non-`NULL` parameter. `COALESCE` is a short hand `CASE` expression, and uses [Data Type Precendence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to determine the returned data type.

As a result, this is why `ISNULL` returns what you expect, there is no implicit conversion in your query for the non-`NULL` variable.

For the `COALESCE` there **is** implicit conversion. `binary` has the **lowest** precedence of *all* the data types, with a rank of 30 (at time of writing). The value `1` is an int, and has a precedence of 16; far higher than 30.

As a result `COALESCE(@bin8, 1)` will implicitly convert the value `0xAAAAAAAA01BB3A35` to an `int` and then return that value. You see this as `SELECT CONVERT(int,0xAAAAAAAA01BB3A35)` returns `29047349`, which your first "bad" value; it's not "bad", it's correct for what you wrote.

Then for the latter "bad" value, we can convert that `int` value (`29047349`) back to a `binary`, which results in `0x0000000001BB3A35`, which is, again the result you get.

TL;DR: checking return types of functions is important. `ISNULL` returns the data type of first parameter and will implicitly convert the second if needed. For `COALESCE` it uses Data Type Precedence, and will implicitly convert the returned value to the data type of with the highest precedence of **all** the possible return values.